# Can we pass Array Values in Radio Button in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
<tr>
    <td>Balance</td>
    <td><?php echo form_radio('balance',array('Yes' => 'Yes', 'No' => 'No'), $this->input->post('balance') ? $this->input->post('balance') : $user->balance);  ?></td>
</tr>
```

for the above code i want to store either yes or no in database. I mean user should be able to choose either he wants to allocate balance or he doesn't.  But i am getting a error **Message: Array to string conversion** 
How can i store just yes or no in my database while editing a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I will be in this condition then i will make the database column default value as 'No' and use below code for save 'Yes' if user select the radio button...

```
<td>Balance</td>
<td><?php echo form_radio('balance','Yes', $this->input->post('balance') ? $this->input->post('balance') : $user->balance);  ?></td>
```

Comment: Thanks your code works! but can you please tell me if i can pass radio option yes or no in array?